# Injecting EJB into JAX-RS REST controller

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs

I'm building a Java EE application for an assignment. I'm required to use JPA for persistence, EJB's to encapsulate my business logic, and a web interface for presentation. Spring is not allowed.

My application consists of a root Maven project and 4 Maven sub-projects: one for my model layer (JPA entities), one for my business layer (EJBs), one for my presentation layer (the web application) and one to build an EAR. I'm deploying the EAR to Glassfish.

However, I'm having some issues putting everything together. I have an entity class in my model layer (JAR module) like this:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int productId;

    ...
}
```

I've then created a service bean in my business layer (EJB module) to encapsulate transaction logic:

```
@Stateless
public class ProductService {
    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "DummyContext" )
    EntityManager em;

    public Product findById( int id ) {
        return em.find( Product.class, id );
    }

    public List<Product> getAll() {
        TypedQuery<Product> query = em.createQuery( "SELECT p FROM Product p", Product.class );
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

And finally, I've created a JAX-RS controller in my presentation layer (WAR module) that I'm trying to access my product service from using REST.

JAX-RS setup:

```
@ApplicationPath( "/api" )
public class ApplicationConfig extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {
}
```

Controller:

```
@Path( "/products" )
public class ProductController {
    @Inject
    private ProductService productService;

    @Path( "/all" )
    @GET
    @Produces( "text/plain" )
    public String getAll() {
        return "Nothing interesting yet";
    }
}
```

As you can see the REST controller doesn't do anything yet. Still, this example now fails. The first time I attempt to access `\api\products\all` after deploying, it throws the following exception:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet wedvich.ApplicationConfig threw exception`

`org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [ProductService] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private wedvich.ProductController.productService]. Possible dependencies [[Session bean [class wedvich.ProductService with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [ProductService], Session bean [class wedvich.ProductService with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [ProductService]]]`

`org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [ProductService] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private wedvich.ProductController.productService]. Possible dependencies [[Session bean [class wedvich.ProductService with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [ProductService], Session bean [class wedvich.ProductService with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [ProductService]]]`

Any subsequent requests then produce the following exception:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet wedvich.ApplicationConfig threw exception`

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context`

Why is this happening? Is there any obvious way to fix it with what I have now, or is the project organization/architecture I've attempted inherently flawed?

I've almost exclusively worked with .NET and ASP.NET MVC before for this kind of project, so trying to do it in Java with the constraints I listed at the beginning of the post is new to me. It's very much possible that I've screwed something up when dabbling with Maven or something else, but I don't know what to look for. Please let me know if there's any more information I can provide that would be relevant, and I'll edit it in.

Comment: Have you tried annotating ProductService field with @EJB annotaion? If yes I would suggest you to check if everything is correctly deployed.

Comment: When annotating it with `@EJB`, my example works. But if I try to actually use the `productService`, I now get a NullPointerException, so it doesn't seem like the EJB is injected at all. Any hints on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that ProductController is managed by container? May be you could try annotating it in addition with `@Statless` annotation to be sure it is managed by a container.

Comment: You annotate something with stateless if you want it to be an EJB, and that is not the case here since its a JAX-RS controller. See how the error is coming from Weld? That means that injection is being attempted so it is most definitely "server managed".

Comment: did you maybe move your ProductService from one package to another and didn't maven clean?

Answer (score 0):

you should inject the interface not the class itself !